# How to restrict ordinary user accessing all views

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

**I want to restrict users with role="ordinary" accessing other Controller views**

example... I have add views under **JobsController** so

if current login user has a user role="ordinary" basically he or she cant proceed to that and it will prompt, you are restricted accessing that page.

and if current user login has a user role="admin" he or she can proceed

I have this code below under AppController.php

```
 public function isAuthorized($user)
    {
        if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') {        
                return true;
        }
        if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'ordinary') {

            $allowedActions = ['index', 'logout', 'add'];
            if(in_array($this->request->action, $allowedActions)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
```

Comment: Instead of doing too much php code, you could just use a very simple config file, e.g. via [TinyAuth](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tinyauth).

Comment: i checked the link you send, for me its hassle can you just help me doing php way like if role=admin

Comment: Do you know you can put a custom `isAuthorized` function in any controller? Any controller that doesn't have a custom one will use this one. And you can call this one from your custom one, if you want to share functionality.

Answer (score -1):

*You can just put like this*

```
<?php
if($this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.role') == 'admin'){
  /// display the views
  /// if current login user has admin role
}
else{
   echo"You are not allowed to access this area";
}
?>
```

**role** must be present in users table field.

Hope it help your problem

Comment: If you echo `$this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.role')`, what does it show you?

Comment: I thought its ok, I did not test many cases @GregSchmidt  it will just display the user role

Comment: @distromob, it certainly *should* display the user role. Knowing whether or not it *does* will help to solve the problem.

Comment: just edit my answer sir @GregSchmidt or you post a new one, so that other users will understand

Comment: I'm asking @user143 what it shows in his situation.